# turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults

Tags: c#, asmx

I am using asmx webservice that work in some cases and getting exception :

> ***System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.***

I have to try to turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults by adding this to web.config but I got invalid child 
 :

```
 <configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="debug">
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
... 
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

any suggestion PLEASE.

Answer (score 1):

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
   <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="debug">
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
    ...
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @Abzakhus what does it mean? Did you get Configuration exception or you didn't get exception details when error occurs?

Comment: Do you have SDK installed on your workstation? Why you don't use C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SvcConfigEditor.exe?