# How do I debug CRM Connection Error in SSIS Package?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis, dynamics-crm, kingswaysoft

I am using KingswaySoft to connect to Microsoft Dynamics CRM in an SSIS Package using Visual Studio 2015.  I am receiving the following error when I try to run the Package on the server.

> Data Flow Task:Error: KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCrm.CrmServiceException: CRM service call returned an error: An error has occurred when retrieving metadata for CRM entity 'ccseq_amaccount': CRM service call returned an error: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

I see several questions about how to add a config key to turn on the IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults for WCF applications (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260245/turn-on-includeexceptiondetailinfaults) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599107/turn-on-includeexceptiondetailinfaults)), but nothing that specifically tells me how to turn this on for an SSIS Package.  Any other methods of seeing more error details would also be welcome.

Comment: The suggestions mentioned should be applied to the Dynamics CRM web.config file. I would however strongly recommend against doing so. Instead, check  the EventViewer on the Dynamics CRM application server or use the CrmDiagTool (https://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com/) to capture a trace if you're working with an On Premise environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for choosing KingswaySoft as your integration solution. This message"The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error." is coming from CRM server side, and it doesn't really help identify the problem. To get more details about the error you are receiving, you would have to turn on CRM trace log on CRM server side.

To turn on CRM trace log for CRM on-prem, you can use the following tool.

- https://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com/

After you have turned on the trace log, you can run the task, and CRM server will generate some log files under C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Trace folder. The log file is big, and not easy to read, so you would use one of the following tools to read the log files.

- https://pfecrmtracetool.codeplex.com/
- https://crmtracereader.codeplex.com/

For CRM Online, you would need to contact the CRM Online support team for assist.